# How to solve theano Segmentation fault?

Tags: anaconda, theano

I am running a python file which content is:

```
import theano.tensor as T
```

This gives me a Segmentation fault.
I am using anaconda.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Hi! Welcome! Can you give some more details, for instance, the OS, Anaconda version, how you installed Theano, Python version, and if it gives the same error from the Python command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem after I updated scipy from version 0.17.1 to version 0.18.0

Try to create a virtual environment with conda (from Anaconda) only for theano, with the correct versions of scipy and numpy:

```
conda create --name theano_env theano python=2.7
```

or (for python 3.5):

```
conda create --name theano_env theano python=3.5
```

It solved the problem for me.